# Is there a simple way to copy text from the debug console of PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a sane way to copy log text from the PyCharm console, instead of selecting it slowly with the mouse (espacially when there's a bundance of text there)? There seem to be no "Select All" from the debug console. 
Is it on porpose? Is there any way to copy (all of) the text from the console sanely?

I do hope the guys and girls at JetBrain do understand that Notepad++ is wayyyy more easy when looking at/analysing logs?

Answer (score 0):

I just click into the debug console window and press Ctrl-A (standard Windows shortcut for select all). Followed by Ctrl-C to copy and then Ctrl-V to paste it into another app (notepad++ or something).

Comment: Nope. That doesn't seems to work... not on my home machine (community version) at least... Odd! Checked it now and it DOES work on my office (pro. version). Hope that's not a pro feature :)

Comment: Odd indeed. I'm using the community version (2017.3) myself on my office laptop.

Answer (score 0):

if you have vim emulator on it won't work. Turn it off by going to Tools and deselecting vim emulator. After that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the text in the console. If that doesn't work you might have a mapping over the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut, it's worth checking that out.

Comment: It's kind of fixed by itself... Anyway VIM? Really? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With VIM emulation on:

1. Use scrollbar to scroll to the end of what you want to copy. (click/drag bar)
2. Click and drag up to highlight a few lines.
3. Use scrollbar again to scroll to the start of what you want to copy.
4. Shift/click at the start of the text you want to copy. (should now be highlighted)
5. Right click and select copy.

This isn't as quick as Ctrl-A, but quicker than turning VIM emulation off/on.
This worked for me in the Python Console, windows 10, PyCharm Community 2018.1.2